# Maximum and minimum quantity of a product

Tags: api

Good Morning!

I need to create an API that returns the maximum and minimum quantity of a product.
What methods can I use?

Comment: Your question is not descriptive. Please elaborate it little bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create first etc/webapi.xml

example

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
 <route url="/V1/plugin/abc/:productid" method="GET">
    <service class="Company\Plugin\Api\Product\ProductdetailIterface" method="getmaxminQty"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
 </route>
</routes>
```

Then create the Interface  Company\Plugin\Api\Product\ProductdetailIterface and the method getmaxminqty

For the Implementation Create a class inside Company\Plugin\Model\Product\ProductDetail and add the method (Which you must implement because of Interface implementing) getmaxminqty

```
 public function getmaxminqty($productId)
 {
  Your code

 }
```

Create a di.xml inside etc and add this lines

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Company\Plugin\Api\Product\ProductdetailIterface" type="Company\Plugin\Model\Product\ProductDetail"/>
 </config>
```